# Конфуз с запросами LINQ (теория онли)

Tags: c#, linq

Любопытная вещь:
  вот такой запрос отрабатывает без ошибок:

```
IdentityUserRole userRole = user.Roles.Single(r => r.UserId == user.Id);
IdentityRole role = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Id == userRole.RoleId);
```

Но если совмещу в один, то вылетает ошибка сервера:

```
IdentityRole role = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Id == user.Roles.Single(ur => ur.UserId == user.Id).RoleId);
```

Почему так происходит? Может, как-нибудь можно безопасно исправить второй запрос или особой разницы нет? Мне почему-то кажется, что один запрос использовать всегда рациональней, чем два...

Comment: (1) А какая ошибка? (2) Ну, у вас во втором варианте кода внутренний запрос выполняется на _каждой_ итерации внешнего запроса, так что не факт, что это реально будет улучшение (разве что по дороге оптимизатор сообразит).

Comment: @VladD, ну просто на странице в браузере вместо соответствующего представления выводится текст с надписью "внутренняя ошибка сервера".. С ASP.NET работаю впервые, IIS "дебажить" не научился ещё)

Comment: при ef-запросах, лямбда-выражение присваивается expression body, который строит дерево выражений, по которому потом будет строиться конкретный sql-запрос, поэтому это лямбда-выражение надо строить настолько простым, насколько потом это может разобрать sql-провайдер.

Comment: обычно, если Вы в C# передаете в качестве аргумента другую функцию (например Fun(FunIn(x));), то компилятор сначала вычислит внутреннюю функцию, а затем результат вычислений подставит во внешнюю функцию (так называемые "строгие вычисления"). [Но .net эмулирует нестрогую модель вычисления посредством делегатов и expression](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стратегия_вычисления), поэтому _user.Roles.Single(ur => ur.UserId == user.Id).RoleId_ не будет вычисляться до передачи в _roleManager.Roles.Single_, а провайдеру обработать самостоятельно это не по зубам

Comment: @guitarhero Дебажить iis не обязательно, 500-ые ошибки IIS пишет в журнал событий windows, можете там поискать информацию об исключении

Comment: @Qutrix, всё, понял, спасибо большое! Совсем забыл про отложенность методов))

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, так-то оно так, но у меня даже не 500 ошибка была, а просто текст, что произошла ошибка. Никаких больше деталей не указывалось)

Comment: "Мне почему-то кажется, что один запрос использовать всегда рациональней, чем два..." - если говорить про удобство поддержки и понимания кода другими разработчиками, то как раз наоборот. На некоторых проектах есть даже требование, чтобы все промежуточные результаты имели осмысленное имя. Возводить в абсолют, конечно, не надо, но иметь в виду полезно